# Classify exam grades into leagues

Tags: php, json

Hey guys I want to make an academic-oriented matching website that allows boys and girls to find their potential partners through academic performance and hobbies.

I was just thinking about convert quantity of exam grades eg. A, B, C and convert them into leagues like S-class, A-class. First I want to convert exam grade A into integer of 5, exam grade B into integer of 4 and so on. Then I sum them up and classify them into their respective classes.

The original and tiring code... I'm not sure whether it's going to work.

```
$obtaindata = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE primaryemel="' . $_COOKIE['smkdtuser'] . '"'));

$pmrresults = json_decode($obtaindata['pmr']);
$spmresults = json_decode($obtaindata['spm']);
$upsresults = json_decode($obtaindata['upsr']);

function calculateClassForPMR ($pmrresults) {
$aquality = (int)$pmrresults['a'] * 5;
$bquality = (int)$pmrresults['b'] * 4;
$cquality = (int)$pmrresults['c'] * 3;
$dquality = (int)$pmrresults['d'] * 2;
$gquality = (int)$pmrresults['g'] * 1;

$additup = $aquality + $bquality + $cquality + $dquality + $gquality;

//Classify sum of scores to their respective class
if ($additup => 35) {$classified = "s";}
elseif ($additup >= 29 && $additup <= 34) {$classified = "a";}
elseif ($additup >= 23 && $additup <= 28) {$classified = "b";}
elseif ($additup >= 17 && $additup <= 22) {$classified = "c";}
elseif ($additup >= 11 && $additup <= 16) {$classified = "d";}
elseif ($additup >= 0 && $additup <= 10) {$classified = "e";}
else {$classified = "wtf";};

return $classified; }
```

Don't blame me though ,I was just started learning php and try to do something weird...

Any replies or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: what goes wrong with the code ? what formats do you use in the database ... post error please ...

Comment: ""I'm not sure whether it's going to work."

Isn't that what testing is all about?

Comment: I don't want to rent another server just to test it... it's costly. But it's like a user inputted 4A 1B 1C and 1D... what is the best format to store them. I was thinking like store it like JSON object like Facebook do?

Comment: What’s the reason for the *json-decode* tag?

Comment: Oh yea I supposed to store the quantities of grades obtained in integer anyway, I was worried about that php form processor will store them in strings.

Answer (score 0):

when using json_decode i assume that you have `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}` something like this containt in that tabel row. Try to use :

`$pmrresults = var_dump(json_decode($obtaindata['pmr'], true))` then you can use `$pmrresults['a'];`

You have to `json_encode()` when you store values to DB

`I don't want to rent another server just to test it... it's costly.` ... user XAMPP it's free for testing.

Comment: How to force PHP to change data type from string to integer when I ask the user to type in their grade point quantity

Comment: well, if your user inputs 4D you can do `$value = substr($var,0,-1);` where `$var = '4D';` and `$letter = substr($var,-1);` -> it results in $letter = D and `$value = 4` where $value is an integer